# Compiler design: How are the initialize conditions for data-flow problems set?

Tags: compilers, data-flow-analysis

Consider a typical data-flow problem, for example, reaching definitions or available expressions.

I am struggling to understand how $IN$ and $OUT$ of the basic blocks are initialized. For example, for available expressions, we initialize $OUT[B] = U$ for all $B$, that is we assign each $OUT[B]$ all expressions, while we assign $OUT[B] = \emptyset$ for the Reaching definitions initialization. Why do we assign $OUT[B] = U$ for available expressions? This seems kind of counter-intuitive given that for a basic block with no code, no expression is available?

**Edit**

To give more detail on what I mean by "Reaching definitions" and "Available Expressions".

Reaching definitions: Determine a set of definitions reaching the entry and exit of each block of the control flow graph, where a definition $d$ reaches a point $p$ if there is a path from the point immediately following $d$ to $p$, such that $d$ is not redefined along that path.

Available expressions: An expression $e$ is available at program point $p$ if $e$ is computed on every path to $p$ and the value of $e$ has not changed since the last time $e$ is computed on $p$.

Reaching definitions is a forward problem where the meet operator is union, while available expression is a forward problem where the meet operator is intersection.

Comment: You'll want to define your context a bit more precisely. Different references use different names.

Not a full answer but: The best way to think about this is that you're really working with a lattice. It turns out that data-flow problems all fit into a nice framework. Depending on weather your intersecting sets or union-ing sets, your bottom/top elements will be different.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to add a little more details. If I am union-ing sets, the top element is the $\emptyset$ right? And if I am intersecting sets the top element is $U$, correct? Does that mean the initialization always assigns the top element w.r.t. to the lattice defined by dataflow problem at hand?

Comment: It depends on the flow problem but in general either top or bottom will by the most conservative option and its a frequent choice

Comment: I think this what I am trying struggling with: Why is choosing $U$, i.e. all expression for the available expressions problem the most conservative option? Is it not more conservative to assume that no expressions are available (in the sense that if we assume an expression is available when it is actually not, this would lead to wrong results, right)?